# link a helpers in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, link-to, helper

I want to call a Helper method from a link like this:

```
 <p><%= link_to fp.name,  lookingFoodPreferences(fp.name) %></p>
```

and this is the helper in application_controller.rb:

```
 def lookingFoodPreferences
    @prefer = Recipe.Where(food_preference: 'params[id]')
 end
```

This is the error:

```
Showing C:/Sites/curry-nation/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where     line #33 raised:

wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to write a scope for this. The rails way of doing this is to just pass the object to a restful url helper

```
=link_to fp.name, recipe_url(fp)
```

If you are unsure what helpers you have available just run

```
rake routes |grep recipe
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<p><%= link_to fp.name,  lookingFoodPreferences(fp.id) %></p>
```

in helper:

```
def lookingFoodPreferences(id)
  @prefer = Recipe.Where(food_preference: id)
end
```